# Import VSTS task group with dataSourceBindings

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to define `dataSourceBindings` in the json of a task group I intend to reuse in release definitions. My task group is basically to deploy a web app with some custom actions. On the parameters I expose on the group, I want to populate the picklists with proper values from AzureRM endpoint like the subscriptions, resource groups, web apps and slots available.

To achieve it, I created a first template from the VSTS UI I then exported to edit in JSON. Based on multiple posts and examples availables in VSTS tasks repo, I defined my dataSourceBindings as:

```
"dataSourceBindings": [
    {
        "target": "ResourceGroupName",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "dataSourceName": "AzureResourceGroups"
    },
    {
        "target": "WebAppName",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "dataSourceName": "AzureRMWebAppNamesByType",
        "parameters": {
            "WebAppKind": "app"
        }
    },
    {
        "target": "SlotName",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "dataSourceName": "AzureRMWebAppSlotsId",
        "parameters": {
            "WebAppName": "$(WebAppName)",
            "ResourceGroupName": "$(ResourceGroupName)"
        },
        "resultTemplate": "{\"Value\":\"{{{ #extractResource slots}}}\",\"DisplayValue\":\"{{{ #extractResource slots}}}\"}"
    }
]
```

I was able to import my task group in VSTS. But once added to a release definition the picklists were still empty.
Then I tried to export the previously imported group and noticed the `dataSourceBindings` field was empty.

Is importing a group task with `dataSourceBindings` supported?
If yes, what could possibly go wrong with mine?

Comment: Can you show the entire of your VSTS extension? Besides, you can also refer Azure App Service Deploy task https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment/task.json and the blog Service endpoints – Data sources https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/15/service-endpoints-data-sources/.

Comment: Here a gist of my entire task group https://gist.github.com/ggirard07/ce293f1480fede68302662e2d571962d. The first link you provided seems broken, but I think I used it already anyway. Please note I am trying to achieve this in a task group, not in a VSTS extension.

Comment: Task group is not support. You can use build extension task instead.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Please specify. Do you mean `dataSourceBindings` are not supported within task groups?

Comment: Yes it looks to me like `dataSourceBindings ` usage is not supported in task groups